# Issues with changing color of basic Kivy app

Tags: python, kivy

I created a simple text-to-speech app with Kivy, using the FloatLayout option but am having trouble changing the color of the GUI without actually creating a .kv file (which I do not wish to do). The code of my app is here:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
import requests
from threading import Thread
import os

class ButtonApp(App):

    def talk(self):
        self.info.text = self.text.text
        command = "say %s" % (self.text.text)
        os.system(command)


    def say(self,instance):
        t = Thread(target=self.talk)
        t.start()
    def build(self):

        self.b = FloatLayout()


        self.info = Label(text="Hello!", pos=(20,400) ,size_hint=(1,0.5), font_size="40sp")

        self.text = TextInput(text='Hello!', pos=(20,200), size_hint=(1,0.5))

        self.submit = Button(on_press=self.say,text='Submit',pos=(20,100), size_hint=(1,0.5))

        self.b.add_widget(self.info)

        self.b.add_widget(self.text)

        self.b.add_widget(self.submit)

        self.b.bind()

        return self.b




if __name__ == "__main__":
    ButtonApp().run()
```

Like I mentioned beforehand, all the suggestions I found doing prior research involved either Canvas (which I am not using), or creating a .kv file. Is there a pure python-kivy method of changing the color of a GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do anything in pure python, though the reason you see so many kv examples is because it's easier and more concise due to being a more domain specific language, so I don't recommend avoiding it.

What kind of change do you actually want to make? For instance, you can change the background image of the Button with the `background_normal` or `background_down` properties (which take a filepath to an image), or tint its colour by setting its `background_color` to e.g. `(1, 0, 0, 1)` for red.

Comment: I specifically want to change the background color of the entire window, as it is black by default. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I also attempted to change the floatlayout color with self.b.background_color = (1,0,0,1)

Comment: FloatLayout doesn't have a background_color property. Did you mean to draw a Rectangle and change the colour of that? Do you have a code source that you're trying to follow?

Comment: Anyway, the Window itself has a property `clearcolor` that does what you want. You can do e.g. `from kivy.core.window import Window; Window.clearcolor = (1, 0, 0, 1)`.

Comment: The kivy.core.window property worked exactly as you anticipated. Thanks a lot!